# Is it possible to add something extra to HSSFCell?

Tags: java

Is it possible, and if yes, then how to add something specific into `specialArrayList case 3:`?
Example what is not working :

```
specialArrayList.add(formatter.formatCellValue("\""+ cell+ "\""));
```

I need that ONLY into `specialArrayList` (`case 3:`) all data what I'm adding from `HSSFCell cell` was with `"`, but in  Excel file value of cell is without `"`.
Excel cell value - VALUE I need in `specialArrayList` "VALUE". ("\"VALUE\"")

```
 ArrayList<String> specialArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

...

```
for (int j = 1; j < sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1; j++) {
    int no = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    HSSFRow rov = sheet.getRow(j);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        HSSFCell cell = rov.getCell(i, org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                firstArrayList.add(formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                break;
            case 1:
                secondArrayList.add(formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                break;
            case 2:
                thirdArrayList.add(formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                break;
            case 3:
                specialArrayList.add(formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                break;
            }
```

P.S: And, please, if you will downvote, let me know why, that I could prevent my mistakes in future. Thanks!

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. You can add whatever `String` you wish to your array, because it's an `ArrayList<String>`. If you need a different type, then no, you can't.

Comment: Unfortunately English is not my Mother language, hoped that is clear enough.

Comment: No it's not clear enough yet, especially what you mean by this: "I'm adding from cell was with `"`, but in Excel file value of cell is without `"`"

Comment: Hope now is better, anyway thanks.

Comment: I've never used HSSF, but for what I can see on the [docs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellType.html) you can try to get the cell type. If it's a string, add it. If not, convert the contents to one, or define your own string to return in each case. Your question is either still unclear or you need further comprehension on the basics

Comment: Never thought that it's so hard just to explain :) Edited, if even after that it's not clear, then I don't know what.

Comment: No, not yet. Having a double quote matters only if the compiler or runtime says so and if you escape them or not. The question might be a lot clearer if you are getting some kind of error and you show it. Otherwise it's just a formatting task of your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That what i meant, was so close...

```
                           case 7:
                                invoice_nr.add("\"" + formatter.formatCellValue(cell) + "\"");
                                break;
```